# Should I localise the error messages in my exceptions?

Tags: c#, exception

I've been working on data import functions for a library recently and I found myself doing this:

```
throw new InvalidDataException(string.Format("Line number {0} is {1} characters instead of {2}", lineNumber, line.Length, ValidLineLength))
```

That's useful debugging information to an English speaker. If it crops up in the Windows Event Log somewhere or gets displayed to a user they will have much more information than someone who doesn't understand the language.

What if the writer of the code doesn't use English (for whatever reason) and they create an error message like this?

```
throw new InvalidDataException("悲しい機能は悲しいです")
```

To everybody that uses the code and speaks the same language, that's great. For the rest of us... what does this mean when we log it?

What are your reasons for and against localising error messages?

Comment: Well, if they are using the .NET class library, they will already have to be pretty well versed in English to recognize the class names, et al.  And of course, users should *never* see the text of your exceptions.

Comment: I asked a similar question recently, you may find it helpful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308132/should-logging-be-affected-by-internationalisation

Comment: @Kirk Woll Why should they *never* see the text of exceptions? Of course, they shouldn't ever see them popping to the front end but what is wrong with them in log files? Assuming that you aren't silly enough to put secure information in your exception text.

Comment: @fletcher Thanks. That's the main thrust of this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your exception statement, `throw`, `new`,  `InvalidDataException`, `string` and `Format` are all in English.   Any programmer using your library (or for that matter, coding in any common programming language) is going to need to speak English.